# Randomly click links from a text file

Tags: python, selenium

I have a list of 10 links in a textfile(links.txt) that currently works with the code below;

```
with open("links.txt") as in_file:
    for url in in_file:
        try:
            driver.get(url.strip())
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),"Go")]").click()
        except:
            continue
```

How do i iterate only 3 of the 10 links randomly?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Use the appropriate method(s) of the `random` package to pick out three items from your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```py
import random

with open("links.txt") as in_file:
    sampled = random.sample(list(in_file), 3)
    for url in sampled:
        try:
            driver.get(url.strip())
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),"Go")]").click()
        except:
            continue
```